# C++ 17 shared_mutex : why read lock is even necessary for reading threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

In the example given in
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex

A `std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex>` is used in the `get()` method so

> Multiple threads/readers can read the counter's value at the same time.

I wonder why the lock is even necessary for reading threads here? Is it for the consideration of variable's across thread visibility, so the reading thread is ensured to read up-to-date value of the variable (not the local copy in the cache of the CPU core where the thread is running in, which could be outdated) ?

Comment: Because if you try to read while it's being modified by another thread you will read incoherent rubbish. You must make sure the information is safe for reading before doing so.

Comment: `s/C++11/C++17/`